# Channel Form refuses to set Status to entry

Tags: safecracker, channel, status

I found a year old post regarding this issue as well ([Setting entry status with Channel Form](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26153/setting-entry-status-with-channel-form)) but no apparent solution.

Has anyone come upon one yet?

Basically I can do this:

```
{status_menu}
    <select name="status">
        {select_options}
    </select>
{/status_menu}
```

But no matter if I am logged in as a super admin, regular user or even a guest, the entry saves with the intended status. It's like the field is being ignored.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I had set a specific status in Admin > Channel Administration > Channel Form, which it turns out, overrides anything in the template code.

When I returned this to "-- Use Channel Default --", it became possible to set the entry status as expected.